# Get FinishFloorHeight of IfcSpace using Xbim

Tags: c#, ifc, xbim

I'm trying to get the FinishFloorHeight of IfcSpace using Xbim.

Any idea of how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the examples at [xbim docs](https://docs.xbim.net/examples/excel-space-report-from-ifc.html), you will see how to get data for a space. To get finish floor height as defined in your link, you can use this code:

```cs
private static double? GetFinishFloorHeight(IIfcSpace space)
{
    return space.IsDefinedBy
        .SelectMany(r => r.RelatingPropertyDefinition.PropertySetDefinitions)
        .OfType<IIfcElementQuantity>()
        .Where(qs => qs.Name == "Qto_SpaceBaseQuantities")
        .SelectMany(qset => qset.Quantities)
        .OfType<IIfcQuantityLength>()
        .Where(q => q.Name == "FinishFloorHeight")
        .FirstOrDefault()?.LengthValue;
}
```